# Best way to combine `grep -n` output with `vim +`

Tags: unix, grep, vi

This seems like something that could be quite useful and yet and I can't find the answer... The output of `grep -n` is something like this:

```
$ grep -inR Poinsot_1992 *
formulation_bc.tex:83:al.~\cite{Poinsot_1992a}, pressure is chosen over temperature as a convenient primitive
refs_final.bib:33594:@article{Poinsot_1992a,
```

How can I feed this to vim so that it opens these 2 files at the lines where the expression is found. Right now, I manually copy the line number which should not be necessary.

```
vim formulation_bc.tex +83
```

Can I modify the way grep outputs its results? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way 'round: the [file:line](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184) plugin teaches vim to treat `file:line` like `file +line`.

Comment: Nice, I guess I didn't use the right keywords as I was searching for it ! Works like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the output of `grep` to `vim` and use the [gF](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#gF) family of motions to move to the file under the cursor.

```
grep -inR Poinsot_1992 * | vim -
```